# mySQL REGEXP to SELECT information_schema.COLUMNS with capital letters in COLUMN_NAME

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to create a query that will SELECT only the rows with a mixture of lower case and upper case letters in the designated WHERE condition column.  What tweak does my REGEXP need?

The results I am expecting from the query below are:

- book_of_the_Bible
- Bible_trivia_category_reference

I need the query to be re-usable for other databases.  I am not wanting to match "Bible" with the REGEXP.

These are my 2 unsuccessful attempts:

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME` , `COLUMN_NAME` FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="elve1522_elversiculodeldia" AND `COLUMN_NAME` != LOWER(`COLUMN_NAME`)
```

*There were no results*

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME` , `COLUMN_NAME` FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="elve1522_elversiculodeldia" AND (`COLUMN_NAME` COLLATE utf8_general_ci) REGEXP '^[A-Z]+$';
```

*Results had only lower case column names.  It selected 32 / 63 rows.  There are only 2 rows where COLUMN_NAME contais upper case letters and neither were selected.*

**For future reference and with the help of Stack Overflow users the correct query is:**

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME` , `COLUMN_NAME` FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="elve1522_elversiculodeldia" AND (`COLUMN_NAME` COLLATE utf8_bin) REGEXP '[A-Z]+[a-z]+' ;
```

Comment: Your regex is one or more of the characters A-Z. No underscores allowed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify your values by lower and upper case, you need use collate utf8_bin instead of utf8-general_ci, which does not care about case.

To find mixture names with both Upper and Lower cases :

```
WHERE (CNAME COLLATE utf8_bin) REGEXP '[A-Z]+[a-z]+'
```

Your filter "^[A-Z]+$' basically filtered out any titles with non-English characters (like space,underscore ...) .

Comment: These changes were successful.

Answer (score 1):

would you mind trying

SELECT `TABLE_NAME` , `COLUMN_NAME` FROM information_schema.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA="elve1522_elversiculodeldia" AND ((`COLUMN_NAME` = LOWER(`COLUMN_NAME`)) AND (`COLUMN_NAME`= UPPER(`COLUMN_NAME`))) ?

Comment: This query selects all 63 rows.